# How do I count the occurrence of a character in a multidimensional array in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array

```
var
characters : array of array of char;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
spaces : integer;
nolines : integer;
linecounter : integer;
charcounter : integer;
space : char;

begin
  nolines := memo1.lines.count-1;
  setlength(characters, nolines+1);
  for linecounter := 0 to nolines do begin
    setlength(characters[linecounter], length(memo1.lines[linecounter]));
  end;
  space := ' ';
  spaces := 0;
  for linecounter := 0 to nolines do begin
    for charcounter := 0 to Length(characters[linecounter]) do begin
      if characters[linecounter,charcounter] = space then
        spaces := spaces +1;
    end;
  end;
  memo2.Lines.add(inttostr(spaces));
end;
```

I want to count how often a space occurs in my memo1. I have put all the characters in an array for practice but whenever I input text and spaces in the Memo, the count of spaces always returns zero.

Comment: You don't fill `characters` array. Note that Memo.Lines is already a list of strings (a kind of char arrays), and there is no neeed in additional array.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the array. You can count characters from the control directly:

```
function CharCount(Strings: TStrings; Character: Char): Integer;
var
  Line: string;
  C: Char;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for Line in Strings do
    for C in Line do
      if C = Character then
        inc(Result);
end;
```

Then you can simply write

```
Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(CharCount(Memo1.Lines, ' ')));
```

Looking at your code, it essentially works apart from the fact that you don't initialise the array. And you get the array bounds wrong, running off the end of the inner arrays.

One final comment. Your variable named `nolines` is mis-named because it holds one fewer than the number of lines. You should put the number of lines in a variable names `nolines` and loop from `0` to `nolines-1`. A more idiomatic choice of name would be `LineCount`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am trying to exercise though so I would still like to know if it is possible with the array.

Comment: What part do you need help with? You know that you don't populate the array right? And you know that you read out of bounds?

Comment: Mainly I ask that question because, as I see it, the main problem with your code is that you mix lots of different tasks up in one big splurge of code. If you must use a ragged character array then decompose as follows: 1. Function to make ragged array from TStrings. 2. Function to count specified character from ragged array. 3. Function to combine these to give your desired output.